# SQL update of unique Key-Value pair

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has a unique non-clustered constraint on two columns (let's call them `key` and `value`)

```
CREATE TABLE table (
  id varchar(50), key varchar(64) NOT NULL, value varchar(64) NOT NULL, ...
  CONSTRAINT pk_table_id PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id ASC) WITH (...) ON [PRIMARY],
  CONSTRAINT pk_key_value UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ( key ASC, value ASC) WITH (...) ON PRIMARY
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Now I need to write a safe update script that updates all rows that have `key='oldKey'`, where safe update script means it has to be possible to be executed multiple times, without throwing an exception.

What I had at the beginning was:

```
UPDATE table
SET key = 'newKey'
WHERE key = 'oldKey'
```

which worked at the first execution (due to the constraint).

Let's say I have a row with `key='oldKey'` and `value='b'`, that got updated to `key='newKey'` and `value='b'`. Now two new rows are inserted, one with `key='oldKey'` and `value='b'` and the other with `key='oldKey'` and `value='c'`, and the update script is run again. Because the key is updated to `'newKey'` and the key-value pair `newKey, b` already exists, an exception is thrown.

What I'm trying to achieve now, is to make an update statement that updates all rows that have `key='oldKey'` AND no key-value pair `key='newKey' value='b'` already exists, otherwise do nothing.

this is what I tried so far:

```
-- 1st try, nothing is updated
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE key='newKey' AND value IN (SELECT value FROM table WHERE key='oldKey'))
BEGIN
  UPDATE table
  SET key = 'newKey'
  WHERE key = 'oldKey'
END

-- 2nd try, exception thrown
UPDATE table
SET key = 'newKey'
WHERE key = 'oldKey' AND
  (SELECT COUTN(*) FROM table WHERE key='newKey' AND value IN (SELECT value FROM table WHERE key='oldKey')) > 0

-- 3rd try, nothing is updated
UPDATE table
SET key = 'newKey'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE key='newKey' AND value IN (SELECT value FROM table WHERE key='oldKey'))
```

Comment: Your example is a little misleading, as your unique constraint is applied to both columns key + value, where it seems natural to just be on key (hence it's name). Can you include the query that links your final table with the ones with the values to update? Or you use a cursor to loop each update?

Comment: The constraint is correct as it is, it needs to be on both, but I get that calling it key-value pair was misleading, but I couldn't find a better description (maybe key-key pair?). Can you elaborate your question a bit more, I'm afraid I don't get what you're asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE t1
SET key = 'newKey'
from table t1
WHERE key = 'oldKey'
and NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table t2 WHERE t2.key='newKey' AND t1.value=t2.value)
```

Comment: Seems to work, thanks, I'll roll out the update to our test environment and come back with the results

Comment: It's updating `UPDATE t` where `t` is not mentioned anywhere in the entire query. OP I am not sure if you have tested this.

Comment: Well I admit it was a little hastily typed, I meant update t1 and of course the where after from ^^

Comment: I can confirm, the update is working as it's supposed to. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**TRY THIS**:

```
UPDATE t SET key = 'newKey' 
FROM yourtable t
LEFT JOIN yourtable t1 ON t1.value = t.value
    AND t1.key = 'newKey'
WHERE t.key = 'oldKey'
    AND t1.value IS NULL
```

Comment: this give me the violation of unique key contraint `pk_key_value` exception

Comment: I don't understand how you are getting violation, it should work in the same manner as `EXISTS`

Comment: I tried it again and it works, I must have switched the key/value columns when changing it to the real names, sorry